# R - Issues with plotting a Plotly graph using a reactive dataset in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, reactive-programming

**Hi there**

I'm building a Shiny App in R, using Plotly to build my interactive plots.

Users have the choice to filter my data: (1) by geography type; (2) by location (wheres choices relate to geography selection); and (3) service type. After which the user can (theoretically) choose alternative Y variables to plot against ratings (x axis): either number of hotel beds or locations.

*NB: I had previously been using ggplot2, but couldn't find a satisfactory solution to adding tooltips using the ggplotly() command.*

I've got two issues with Plotly at the moment, one of which is straightforward and the other is simply baffling me:

1. Plotly appears to be treating my Loc_count variable as a factor, although it's coded as a numeric (See Image 1). I want Plotly to plot Loc_count as a numeric and, therefore, generate a tally of the number of locations for a particular geography on the Y axis rather than the binary 0 - 1 scale.
2. The other issue is that when I choose Beds on the Y axis, Plotly is not displaying all the observations for each of my rating categories (see image 2). For example, in image 2, there appears to be xxx beds rated Good, whereas in the data there is xxx beds. What appears to be happenning is that Plotly is only displaying data for one observation (i.e. hotel). No idea why.

Due to the size and content of the original dataset I can only provide a mock sample of what the data structure looks like with different variable names:

**Dataset**

```
Data <- data.frame(Loc_count = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
               Hotel = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),
               Region = c(rep("North",10)),
               Authority = c("Bolton","Manchester","Bolton","Bolton","Bradford","Manchester","Preston","Bolton","Preston","Manchester"),
               Town = c("Milton","Warrington","Milton","Leigh-on-Sea","Basildon Town","Gadden","Manchester Central","Marm Central","Marsh","Lemington Spa"),
               Service = c("Motel","Hotel","Motel","Hotel","Hotel","Bedsit","Hotel","Hotel","Hotel","Hotel"),
               Rating = c("Good","Excellent","Excellent","Good","Good","Good","Poor","Adequate","Adequate","Good"),
               Beds = c(100,45,34,55,25,69,55,150,50,50)
               )
```

**UI**

```
       ui <- fluidPage(

   # App title
   titlePanel("Hotel analyser"),

   # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(id = "sidebar",
                   # Input 1: Select geography
                   uiOutput("Geography"),
                   # Input 2: Select location
                   uiOutput("Location"),
                   # Input 3: Select service type
                   uiOutput("Service"),
                   # Input: Select y variables
                   radioButtons("y", "Choose Y variable",
                                c("Beds",
                                  "Locations"),
                                selected = "Locations")
      ),

      # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
      mainPanel(
         # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
         tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                     tabPanel("Bar Chart", plotlyOutput("plot", height = "450px")),
                     tabPanel("Underlying data", dataTableOutput("table"))
         )
      )
   )
)
```

**Server**

```
        server <- function(input, output) {

      # Reactive output/inputs and datasets
      #Geography selection output
      output$Geography = renderUI({
         selectInput(inputId = "Geography",
                     label = "Select geography:", 
                     choices = c("Region","Authority","Town"),
                     selected = "Region")
      })

      Geography <- reactive(switch(input$Geography,
                                   "Region" = Data$Region,
                                   "Authority" = Data$Authority,
                                   "Town" = Data$Town))

      #Location selection output
      output$Location = renderUI({
         selectInput(inputId = "Location", 
                     label = "Select location:", 
                     choices = unique(Geography()),
                     selected = unique(Geography())[1]) 
      })

      datasub2 <- reactive({
         req(input$Location)
         filter(Data, Geography() %in% input$Location)
      })

      #Service selector
      output$Service = renderUI({

         selectInput(inputId = "Service",
                     label = "Select Service Type:",
                     choices = unique(datasub2()[,"Service"]),
                     selected = unique(datasub2()[,"Service"])[1])
      })

      datasub3 <- reactive({
         req(input$Location)
         filter(datasub2(), Service %in% input$Service)

      })

      y <- reactive(switch(input$y, 
                           "Beds" = datasub3()$Beds,
                           "Locations" = datasub3()$Loc_count))

      #  Bar chart
      output$plot = renderPlotly({

         plot_ly(
            datasub3(), x = ~Rating, y = ~y(), type = "bar") %>%
            layout(xaxis = list(title = "X", showgrid = F), yaxis = list(title = "Y"))
      })

      # Generate an data table view of the data ----
      output$table <- renderDataTable({
         datasub3()[,1:7]
      }) 

   } 

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

**Image 1: you can see Plotly is treating my column to tally (Loc_count) as a factor**

[image]

**Image 2: although the plot shows 150 adequate hotels in the North, the data shows there to be 200. Appears to be showing data for only one observation**